# PDEs in their weak form in Comsol

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes, comsol, modeling

If a physical model is not listed in the wizard, we can use Comsol's weak form to enter PDE's (governing equations of a system) in their weak form. How can it be done ?

for example: 2 equations of momentum (2D flow) coupled with continuity equation

$\rho \ v.\nabla v=-\nabla p +\mu \nabla^2 v$

$\nabla .v=0$

This model (well-known) is for calculating velocity and pressure fields

Comment: I would assume that comsol manual to be of help here. Have you looked?

Comment: unfortunately no, i don't have the manual. could u please give me a link for it(and also comsol documentation did not help).

Comment: I don't know Comsol. What I meant to point out is that you are asking people to explain something that is already explained somewhere (the manual). This is not likely a successful strategy. Where did you get a copy of Comsol from that doesn't have a manual? And did you check online with the manufacturer whether they have a help page?

Comment: Comsol solves the coupled pressure and velocity equations (NS equations) easily, waht i meant was to know if it is possible to solve the equatios using weak form or not. because i wanna simulate another model with 5 coupled PDE and i need to examine a simple one before the main project.and im not even able to solve simple NS equations using comsol. so i just need to know if it is possible or not.thanks.

Comment: This document explains how to obtain the weak form of inductive heating equations that can be used in finite element softwares like COMSOL (Weak form interface). It gives the mathematical formulation of the problem and the weak form in vectoriel form and axisymmetric form. https://gum.co/XerZi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "model" is the incompressible (constant density) Navier Stokes problem, the second equation being the mass balance:
$$
\frac{\partial\rho }{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho v)=0
$$
I have worked in the past with Comsol, and I believe that the Navier Stokes weak forms are readily implemented in the CFD module as states the Comsol modeling manual in this [LINK](http://filebox.ece.vt.edu/~hbhudi/Laboratory/Distributed%20Temperature%20Sensing/Gasifier%20simulation/modeling.pdf). You would only have to input the initial values of the (velocity,pressure) field and the boundary conditions. Your model input will be the density and the viscosity

Comsol supports however adding weak contributions to the boundaries or in local points but this is not what you are asking for i presume

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I really need to know if it is possible to solve the equatios using weak form or not. because i wanna simulate another harder model with at least 5 coupled PDE and i need to examine a simple model before the main project.Funny thing is that im not even able to solve simple NS equations using comsol. So i just need to know if it is possible or not.Have u simulated a model with at least 3 coupled PDE before using weak form? Thanks.

Comment: I had done some kind of PDE coupling using the Mathematics module (where you can find the General Form PDE) , that wasnt impossible. 

I suggest that you start with some tutorial cases given by Comsol in their user guide, this should help you handle the use of the modules (CFD and Mathematics)